# Confused by the syntax or grammaticality used in this quote by Karl Marx. Please help?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, quotes

The quote is from the [Manifesto of the Communist Party:](https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1848/communist-manifesto/ch01.htm)

> No sooner is the exploitation of the labourer by the manufacturer, so far, at an end, that he receives his wages in cash, than he is set upon by the other portions of the bourgeoisie, the landlord, the shopkeeper, the pawnbroker, etc.

I understand what this quote means, but I do not understand the way it is worded. Marx uses "no sooner" with "so far", "at an end", and "that" before he gets to using "than", which seems to be the familiar construct. Can someone help untangle this one for me?

Comment: Can you give full source?

Comment: Yes there are various errors in the sentence. My guess is that there is a typographical problem. If you remove the words *so far* and *that he receives his wages in cash* it makes perfect grammatical sense.  It seems as if two different sentences have got jumbled together.

Comment: The source is the Communist Manifesto, by Marx and Engels.

Comment: @surlawda I have a copy on my bookshelf. Can you point to the exact location, please? Presumably it is in the first section *Bourgeois and Proletarians*? Mine is the Penguin Classics 2002 edition with introduction by Gareth Stedman Jones. Don't suppose you are using the same one are you? If so you could just give me the page number.

Comment: @WS2 I have the Norton Critical Edition, but I don't have it with me, and I can't say exactly how this sentence appears in there, or what page it's on, but it is in the first chapter, "Bourgeois and Proletarians." At the moment I am looking at an online edition. The quote as it appears in this question can be found at https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1848/communist-manifesto/ch01.htm#ab2. The simpler translation appears at https://www.armstrongeconomics.com/research/economic-thought/by-author/marx-karl/the-communist-manifesto/

Comment: @surlawda It does appear to be the authentic text of the 1888 English edition - I have it in my copy and have looked at a couple of other on-line editions. They all say the same. The 1888 edition was translated by Samuel Moore. But clearly that passage is a grammatical nightmare. The only thing I can suggest to the OP is that they check it against one of the earlier English editions (there were several, including in 1872) and particularly against a German edition. My presumption is that Samuel Moore, or his typesetter, was having a bad day, but who can say?

Comment: I would understand "exploitation ..., so far, at an end, that he receives his wages in cash" to mean "exploitation ... at an end insofar as he receives his wages in cash".  (I'm guessing the German is something like "insofern zu Ende, dass er ...".)

Answer (score 5):

There are several editions of the Manifesto, and several translations. An easier reading of this sentence is often given as

> No sooner has the labourer received his wages in cash, for the moment
>   escaping exploitation by the manufacturer, than he is set upon by the
>   other portions of the bourgeoisie- the landlord, the shopkeeper, the
>   pawnbroker, etc.

In your version, somewhat more convoluted, the "so far" refers to the exploitation of the laborer up to the point that he receives his wages: with this paycheck, the exploitation that the laborer has been subjected to "so far" has come to "an end." Thenceforth, the laborer will be exploited by other elements of bourgeoisie--i.e., the landlord, etc., will set out to take that laborer's money away. It might be said this way:

> The moment a worker gets his wages, and escapes the exploitation he
>   has suffered thus far at the hands of his boss, he will begin to be exploited
>   by his landlord, etc.

Comment: As I'm not a German speaker I can't help much. Perhaps underlying the problem is some convenient German idiom which doesn't exist in English. But your quoted translation above is certainly more intelligible.

Comment: "...receives his wages *in cash*" is an important part of the quote: a worker receiving his pay in kind or in truck is open to exploitation. But no sooner does the labourer (thanks to the Truck Acts and similar legislation) avoid this by getting paid in cash...

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget this document was originally written in German.  From your quoted translation, I suspect that it wasn't written in Hoch Deutsch.  I'd take the answers above and not worry about the garbled translation you cite.